# How to keep original color in logs for grep | docker | act

Tags: linux, docker, grep

I have started working with [nektos/act](https://github.com/nektos/act) repository to run my Github Actions locally and what I want to do is to display the **original color** logs only for the steps in my workflow at `.github/workflows/lint.yml`. Since the `--verbose` flag does not allow me to filter these logs, I have been using `grep` and it works as expected with the following command.

```
act push --secret-file .secrets --rm | grep -ivw -e "" -e ""
```

and the output is:

[steps-logs-with-grep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG9mW.png)

But, without grep (just act command), the lines that start with:

```
[clang-format-lint/cpp-linters]
```

are colored:

[act-not-steps-filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8laZW.png)

Does anyone know how to keep the act format, but filter for steps only with the original color (yellow/blue)?

**Solution:**

```
unbuffer act push --secret-file .secrets --rm | grep -Ev "|"
```

[final solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2a4A.png)

Comment: Many tools conditionally emit color depending on whether or not their output is attached to a tty. Unless there is some sort of `--always-use-color` option (and some tools do provide this), you're mostly out of luck.

Comment: @larsks The GNU convention is `--color=always`. There's also `unbuffer(1)`:  `unbuffer act ... | grep`.

Comment: Hi @dan, your answer is what I was looking for. It is working now with the original colored output. For anyone interested, you must install `expect` package: https://command-not-found.com/unbuffer package according to your OS since `unbuffer` is part of it. Also, it is working as an alias as well: `alias act_steps_debug='unbuffer act push --secret-file .secrets --rm | grep -ivw -e "" -e ""'`

Comment: @dan, could you please post your solution as an answer? I will need it to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that programs usually only print terminal control sequences (colours) if the output file is a terminal device. Control sequences usually aren't printed if output is piped or redirected to a regular file.

If the command doesn't have an option to force colours (like `--color=always` or similar), you can use the `unbuffer` program from the `expect` package, to make the program behave as if printing to a terminal.

```
unbuffer act ... | grep
```

Be aware that the output will contain control sequence strings, which may interfere with text filtering (using something like grep).